# Verify Green's Theorem for region bounded by the lines $x=2$, $y=0$, $y=2x$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Verify Green's Theorem for the region D bounded by the lines $x=2$, $y=0$, $y=2x$ and the functions $f(x,y)=(2x^2)y$, $g(x,y)=2x^3$.

I have been trying this question for far too long and I can't seem to get it right. On one side I get $32$ and on the other I get $128$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Can you at least write down Green's theorem for a function $f(x,y)$? If yes, can you show us your work.

Comment: Is the identity you work with $\int_{\partial D}f\,dx+g\,dy = \iint_D (g_x-f_y)$?

Comment: Thanks for the links Chantry.
Alex I would love to but currently still learning Latex etc so my attempt would be messy. I am using the formula Rafflesia mentioned and getting ∫∂Dfdx+gdy=128 (after splitting into 3 line segments giving 0+64+64) and ∬D(gx−fy)=32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We split up $\partial D$ into $C_1, C_2, C_3$, where:
\begin{align*}
C_1:\qquad (f, g) &= (2(1 - t), 4(1 - t)) &\text{where } t \in [0, 1] \\
C_2:\qquad (f, g) &= (2t, 0) &\text{where } t \in [0, 1] \\
C_3:\qquad (f, g) &= (2, 4t) &\text{where } t \in [0, 1] \\
\end{align*}
Note that:
\begin{align*}
\int_{C_1} f \, dx + g \, dy
&= \int_0^1 2[2(1 - t)]^2 \cdot 4(1 - t) \cdot -2 \, dt + \int_0^1 2[2(1 - t)]^3 \cdot -4 \, dt \\
&= 2\int_0^1 -2^6(1 - t)^3 \, dt = 2^7 \int_1^0 u^3 \, du = -2^5 \\
\int_{C_2} f \, dx + g \, dy
&= \int_0^1 2(2t)^2 \cdot 0 \cdot 2 \, dt + \int_0^1 2(2t)^3 \cdot 0 \, dt = 0 \\
\int_{C_3} f \, dx + g \, dy
&= \int_0^1 2(2)^2 \cdot 4t \cdot 0 \, dt + \int_0^1 2(2)^3 \cdot 4 \, dt = 2^6 \\
\end{align*}
Thus, we conclude that:
$$
\int_{\partial D} f \, dx + g \, dy
= -2^5 + 0 + 2^6 = 32
$$
which matches what you computed via Green's Theorem.

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou. I see where I went wrong. My parameterization for line C1 was incorrect.